# Access array from outside the function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to access the `letters` array from outside the `onUpdate` function.

**JS:**

```
Sortable.create(el, {
    onUpdate: function(event) {
        var update = event.target.innerText;
        var letters = update.split("");
        console.log(letters);
    }
});
```

I tried having a global variable `letters` and trying to return `letters[0]`.

Update:

```
var letters = [];
Sortable.create(el, {
    onUpdate: function(event) {
        var update = event.target.innerText;
        var letters = update.split("");
        console.log(letters);
    }
    console.log(letters[0]);
});
```

Comment: It should work with a global variable. Please show the code that tries to do that, and explain what's wrong with it.

Comment: Ajax refers to a way of doing client/server communication. I don't see how this has anything to do with the issue. Your problem is rather about variable scope and JS syntax. `console.log(letters[0]);` is invalid where you put it. Also note that `letters` will only have a value after `onUpdate` was **executed**.

Comment: Remove var from the var letters = update.split("");

In the second part you are creating a new variable instead of using the global one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should move "letters" array outside the function and remove "var" inside function:

```js
var letters = [];

Sortable.create(el, {
    onUpdate: function(event) {
        var update = event.target.innerText;
        letters = update.split("");
        console.log(letters);
    }
});
```

Comment: I am getting `undefined` @Ked

Comment: Because, you didnt get onUpdate event yet, before "console.log(letters[0]);"